# PHP mySql fetch all items from table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm really new to PHP and mySql, but I'm trying to figure out how to fetch all items from a table. In my item handler class I'm doing

```
static function getAllItems(){

        $items = array();
        $db = new Database();

        $result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM items");

        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            $items[] = $row;
        }

        return $items;
}
```

and then on the client side I'm doing this to iterate through the items returned and display them, but keep getting an error

> "Fatal error: Call to a member function getTitle() on a non-object"

What am I doing wrong?

```
<div class="table-responsive">
        <?php
        $allItems = ItemHandler::getAllItems();

        if(empty($allItems)){
            echo '<p class="lead text-center">No listings in this category yet.</p>';
        } else {
            echo '<table class="table">

            <tr>
            <th>Image</th>
            <th>Item Name</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Seller</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Purchase</th>
            </tr>';


            foreach($allItems as $item){
                echo "<tr>
                <td>blank</td>
                <td>{$item->getTitle()}</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>{$item->getDescription()}</td>
                <td>test seller</td>
                <td>{$item->getPrice()}</td>
                <td><a href='#'><button type='button' class='btn btn-primary'>Buy</button></a></td>
                </tr>";
            }

            echo '</table>';
        }

        ?>

</div>
```

I don't believe the problem is with any functions from my Item class. I believe it's how I'm creating the items with get all Items. Here's the code anyway. Items is included in my client side file.

```
class Item {
    private $id;
    private $title;
    private $description;
    private $imgPath;
    private $category;
    private $keywords;
    private $postedTimestamp;
    private $updatedTimestamp;
    private $price;
    private $published;

    function __construct($id, $title, $description, $imgPath, $category, $keywords, $postedTS, $updatedTS, $price, $published){
      $this->setId($id);
      $this->setTitle($title);
      $this->setDescription($description);
      $this->setImgPath($imgPath);
      $this->setCategory($category);
      $this->setKeywords($keywords);
      $this->setPostedTimestamp($postedTS);
      $this->setUpdatedTimestamp($updatedTS);
      $this->setPrice($price);
      $this->setPublished($published);
  }

public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }


    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }
//other getters/setters of same format
```

When I do `vardumpvar_dump($allItems[0]);`  this is returned, which is correct...

> array (size=9)   'id' => string '1' (length=1)   'title' => string
>   'Test item' (length=9)   'description' => string 'test description'
>   (length=16)   'imgPath' => string
>   'images/f141705f42bc438e1fa13ce21a04b67cc4568996-test1.gif'
>   (length=57)   'price' => string '45' (length=2)   'postedTS' => string
>   '2014-03-19 01:13:34' (length=19)   'updatedTS' => string '2014-04-16
>   21:39:19' (length=19)   'published' => string '1' (length=1)
>   'category' => string '1' (length=1)

Comment: where's the ` getTitle()` function?

Comment: @Rorschach that's just a basic getter function in my Item class.

Comment: the problem is with getTitle which isn't shown in your code... please show all relevant code

Comment: Make sure it's not an associative array by `var_dump($items[0])`.

Comment: @WereWolf-TheAlpha I included the var_dump response in edit at bottom.

Comment: In your foreach-loop your $item is an associative array but not an instance of your item class as you see by the var_dump response. That's no wonder, because you fetch all rows as associative. You've got to add new instances of your item class while fetching the result from the query.

Comment: Check my answer, as I doubted it was an array and it's that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$item['title']` instead of `$item->getTitle().`

Comment: yep this was it, as explained in answer below. can't use getters for it. thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to your `var_dump` result given below:

> array (size=9) 'id' => string '1' (length=1) 'title' => string 'Test
>   item' (length=9) 'description' => string 'test description'
>   (length=16) 'imgPath' => string
>   'images/f141705f42bc438e1fa13ce21a04b67cc4568996-test1.gif'
>   (length=57) 'price' => string '45' (length=2) 'postedTS' => string
>   '2014-03-19 01:13:34' (length=19) 'updatedTS' => string '2014-04-16
>   21:39:19' (length=19) 'published' => string '1' (length=1) 'category'
>   => string '1' (length=1)

Each `$item` is an associative array and you have `title` and other fields in each item so access it using:

```
$item['title'];
$item['description'];
```

And so on.

Answer (score 0):

Please try like your modify codes.

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "mypass") or
die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("tutorials");
$result = mysql_query("select * from tutorials");
echo "<table border='1' style='border-collapse: collapse'>";
echo "<th>Name of theTutorial</th><th>Pages</th><th>Examples</th><th>Author</th>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
echo"<tr><td>".$row['name']."</td><td>".$row['no_of_pages']."</td><td>".$row['no_of_examples']."</td><td>".$row['author']."</td></tr>";<br>}<br>echo "</table>";<br>mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Please change your code dependable for your need. I expect you will get solve 100%

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a class contains the model of the table, then initialise the setter and getter, after that you can use the fnctions i.e

```
class model{
private $title;
private $description;
private $price;
//...
public function getTitle(){
return $title;
}
//..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an instance of the required object. (Item)

Your code currently pushes all fetched rows into an array.

You need to process those rows.

```
static function getAllItems(){

    $items = array();
    $db = new Database();

    $result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM items");

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $items[] = new Item($row["id"], $row["title"], $row["description"], $row["imgPath"], $row["category"], $row["keywords"], $row["postedTS"], $row["updatedTS"], $row["price"], $row["published"]);
    }

    return $items;
}
```

I'm recommending using PDO with PHP (http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers), because it can do all these 'injections' (and much better if you want to build your application for multiple databases) for you like this:

```
$yourstatement->fetchObject("Item")
```